# aria-hidden true read by JAWS

Tags: wai-aria, jaws-screen-reader

Using jQuery add role alert in #div1, read #div2 content even if it is hidden for JAWS.

```html
<div id="div1">
     some content 
    <div id="div2" aria-hidden="true">
           some content 2 for div
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In the above code i have div2 with aria-hidden true. Using jquery i added attr role as alert in div1. Jaws reader reads content of div2 also, even when i have applied aria-hidden true. Does this mean if we set the role=alert all content is read even if we have set aria-hidden as true.

Answer (score 3):

Support for the aria-hidden attribute was added to JAWS in their 13.0.718 update (February 2012). See the full change log below:

http://www.freedomscientific.com/downloads/jaws/JAWS13-previous-enhancements.asp.

> JAWS now recognizes the aria-hidden attribute so that text that is
>   supposed to be hidden is no longer announced.

It seems to work for me, but I've noticed that tabbable content wrapped in a "hidden" container can still be navigated to and read by JAWS.

Comment: Do you know if there's a bug with IE8 and JAWS15? Testing on that and JAWS is reading content with aria-hidden="true"

Answer (score 2):

Currently, JAWS does not support aria-hidden state in both Internet Explorer and Firefox.

You can use role="presentation" though it is not recommended.

See also:

- [Official JAWS aria support list](http://freedomscientific.com/PDF/visionloss/manuals/DevDoc/JAWS-ARIA-Support.doc)
- [Donald Evans's blog](http://websiteaccessibility.donaldevans.com/2011/06/22/aria-hidden/)

Comment: Your Freedom Scientific link is broken and the blog post is from 2011. JAWS now supports aria-hidden in both IE and Firefox. Here is a validation test from 2013: http://www.html5accessibility.com/tests/hidden2013.html