# Prevent screen readers from reading some text in HTML page

Tags: html, angularjs, wai-aria, screen-readers, jaws-screen-reader

I am using certain text in place of an icon or image which I dont want to read out to users using screen readers like JAWS. How can I prevent this? I had tried `aria-hidden` but it still reads out the content. Is there any effective way ONLY to prevent certain texts on screen from reading out?

Comment: possible duplicate of [aria-hidden true read by JAWS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10820594/aria-hidden-true-read-by-jaws)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to write content that screen readers will ignore?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/672156/is-there-a-way-to-write-content-that-screen-readers-will-ignore)

Comment: What Version of Jaws Are You Running? on which browser ?

Comment: aria-hidden is pretty well supported; can you give a sample of your HTML, and mention which browser you are testing against? Not sure I get your scenario; is it the text or the image you don't want read out?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways you can do this. If it is just an image, then any of the following will cause the image to disappear to a screen reader user:

```
<img src="whatever.ext" alt=""/>
<img src="whatever.ext" role="presentation" />
```

Of course, you can double-up too with this to make it abundantly clear what you mean

```
<img src="whatever.ext" role="presentation" alt="" />
```

These should also work in newer browsers that are strictly ARIA compliant but I have not tested them in all browsers

```
<img src="whatever.ext" aria-label="" />
<img src="whatever.ext" aria-hidden="true" />
<img src="whatever.ext" title="" />
```